# What's the point of filing taxes after paying for them?

Tags: united-states, taxes

https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/when-to-file/due-dates-personal.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200617134358/https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/when-to-file/due-dates-personal.html)) states:

> California grants you an automatic 6-month extension to file your state tax return. No form is required. You must file by October 15, 2020. Your payment is still due by July 15, 2020.

What's the point of filing taxes after paying for them? After = a few weeks/months.

Answer (score 4):

In a normal tax year people have all sorts of reasons why they need an extension. The extension is the need to file the return (in other words the paperwork) it doesn't change the due date for the money.

When using the extended time it is prudent to estimate the numbers so that you overpay. The worst thing would be to miss by so much that you get hit with interest and penalties because you failed to send in enough money by the due date.

So why do people need extensions? One year I didn't get a schedule K-1 until a few days before the due date. I was the first time I was getting one, and didn't want to make a mistake on short notice. But because I was due a refund I didn't face any big issues with the extension.

Others need more time because they realized they were missing documents on April 15th.

> What's the point of filing taxes after paying for them? After = a few
> weeks/months.

Remember the paperwork/return is where you declare all the income and expenses. It is where all the tax related information is gathered and the account is settled. Until that paperwork is submitted the IRS (or the state) doesn't know what your exact situation is.

Comment: ". The extension is the need to file the return (in other words the paperwork) it doesn't change the due date for the money." -> Thanks, this is what I missed. Thanks also for the rest of the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You are required to have paid 100% of your tax liability for the year by the regular tax filing deadline (which is normally April 15 of the following year but is July 15, 2020 for 2019 taxes). So if 2019 your tax payments so far through withholding and estimated taxes haven't reached 100% of your tax liability yet (i.e. you would owe some taxes if you filed your tax return now), you will need to pay that difference by July 15. If not, it will start accruing interest from July 15 until when you actually pay it. Although the government gives you a free extension to file your tax return until October 15, they are not giving you an interest-free loan for the owed amount from the regular deadline until the extended filing deadline.

If you are unsure what your actual owed amount will be, you should err on the side of overpaying and pay the maximum potential amount, because it is better to potentially overpay by a little and get a refund, than to underpay and owe some amount plus interest.